# Vertx run results in resource not found error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, vert.x, lombok

I am trying to run a vertx server with dynamoDB and lombok annotations, and I am unable to get it to work properly. I have added the .jar files for vertx, dynamoDB, and lombok to my classpath. Everything compiles fine in IntelliJ, but I cannot get it to run properly from my terminal.

I get:

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:Server User$ vertx run Server.java 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: Server.java
    at io.vertx.core.impl.verticle.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:73)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:38)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.createVerticles(DeploymentManager.java:184)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeployVerticle$2(DeploymentManager.java:157)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.checkCallHandler(FutureImpl.java:158)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:130)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:102)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.deployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:90)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:574)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIsolatedDeployer.deploy(VertxIsolatedDeployer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.ClasspathHandler.deploy(ClasspathHandler.java:160)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.deploy(RunCommand.java:389)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.run(RunCommand.java:262)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.execute(VertxCommandLauncher.java:230)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:365)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:328)
    at io.vertx.core.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:49)
Failed in deploying verticle 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: Server.java
    at io.vertx.core.impl.verticle.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:73)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:38)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.createVerticles(DeploymentManager.java:184)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeployVerticle$2(DeploymentManager.java:157)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.checkCallHandler(FutureImpl.java:158)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:130)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:102)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.deployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:90)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:574)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIsolatedDeployer.deploy(VertxIsolatedDeployer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.ClasspathHandler.deploy(ClasspathHandler.java:160)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.deploy(RunCommand.java:389)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.run(RunCommand.java:262)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.execute(VertxCommandLauncher.java:230)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:365)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:328)
    at io.vertx.core.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:49)

java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: Server.java
    at io.vertx.core.impl.verticle.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:73)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:38)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.createVerticles(DeploymentManager.java:184)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeployVerticle$2(DeploymentManager.java:157)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.checkCallHandler(FutureImpl.java:158)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:130)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:102)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.deployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:90)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:574)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIsolatedDeployer.deploy(VertxIsolatedDeployer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.ClasspathHandler.deploy(ClasspathHandler.java:160)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.deploy(RunCommand.java:389)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.run(RunCommand.java:262)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.execute(VertxCommandLauncher.java:230)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:365)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:328)
    at io.vertx.core.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:49)
```

Would appreciate some help with this!

Comment: Can you also show us the code you're compiling, and the command line you used to get the error message? Do you use run `vertx run <SomeFile>.java`? That probably will not work.

Comment: vertx run <SomeFile>.java works for smaller vertx projects. It only should be used like that however for testing smaller things. I was able to fix my issue, see the answer that I will post below.

Answer (score 1):

This error simply tells you that the Vert.x CLI could not find the Server.java file in the current working directory.

Given that you use Lombok (which modifies code at compile time), I would recommend to run your Verticle after you compiled it with your IDE or build tool.

Here is a list of [possibilities to start a Verticle](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_run_verticles)

Comment: I wanted to avoid using an IDE for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by creating a fat jar module out of my project. I followed this for help: http://vertx.io/blog/my-first-vert-x-3-application/